# PVRCT Texture Format with glTexStorage2D on Open GL 3.0 ES How?

Tags: textures, opengl-es

I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find the answer.

How can I use glTexStorage2D with PVRCT textures? I've done this:

```
#define GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_PVRTC_4BPPV1_IMG 0x8C02

glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_PVRTC_4BPPV1_IMG, m_uPixelsWide, m_uPixelsHigh );
```

Where the GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_PVRTC_4BPPV1_IMG internal format works for glTexImage2D, but when I run that Tex Storage command, my pvr textures come out black. There are no errors posted, and when I query glGetTexParameteriv, my texture is indeed set to Immutable.

Does PVRCT not work for opengl 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

[Have you checked the Opengl ES 3.0 documentation on glTexStorage2D?](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml)

According to the docs:

> internalformat must be one of the sized internal formats given in Table 1,
>   or one of the compressed internal formats given in Table 2 below.
>   Upon success, the value of GL_TEXTURE_IMMUTABLE_FORMAT becomes GL_TRUE.

There is no macro for PVRCT in table 1 or 2.

[Also have a look at the Apple documentation on PVRCT compression.](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=NxykJ3b-zqwC&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_PVRTC_4BPPV1_IMG&source=bl&ots=Kkl4u27f9f&sig=T1K0iG_RKp5PNYu7KsWQ6l75KCk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNibnpm4rfAhXMVrwKHciDCwMQ6AEwBHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_PVRTC_4BPPV1_IMG&f=false)

According to the docs, the PVRCT format you've cited is used with the
following two Opengl ES functions:
- glTexImage2D
- glCompressedTexImage2D

Both of these functions are used to specify a two-dimensional texture image.
(where as glTexStorage2D specifies the storage for all levels)

Another note from the Apple documentation:

> PVRTC textures must be square. The width/height must be a power of two.

Might be a good idea to check that your textures match this requirement.